# Storing data from a form using nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I need to get some data from a form as POST request and save that data so i can use it on another page.
I am successful at retrieving the data form the form as JSON, but since i am not using any database, i am not able to see the data that i retrieved from the form when i redirect for the next page..

I am new at using jade, nodejs and express. I'd like a opinion on how to retrieve the data that i've sent via post method.
If i use render, it loads the page with all the correct info, but if i reload or change to another page, the data will simple disappear.

Comment: You can store the data in a [session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

Comment: I don't need this data for login purposes, i just need to send the data to the next page. with sessions i can achieve that? and if i close the window, it will be there when i open the page again?

Comment: You can control the lifetime of the session via the session cookie. See the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Redux Persist (state management tool)** or **local storage** to save data. Both of these will save your data in a way that it can be retrieved when you navigate to the next page or even if you reload your page.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by using the middleware cookie-session. I can store the data for the time that i want and i can relaunch the server without loosing information. Thank you for the help anyway :)